# why the error broke out even though the condition is given when the key is the out of range in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my code.

```
def return_day(num):
    days = {1:"Sunday", 2:"Monday", 3:"Tuesday", 4:"Wednesday", 5:"Thursday", 6:"Friday", 7:"Saturday"}
    if (num > 0 or num < 8):
        return days[num]
    return "None"
print(return_day(10))
```

And the error pops up like the following.

```
print(return_day(10))
  File "tf_frame.py", line 14, in return_day
    return days[num]
KeyError: 10
```

Could you please help me explain why the error occurs?

Comment: change the `or` to `and`

Comment: `if (num > 0 or num < 8)` this includes numbers from negative infinite to positive infinite

Comment: Oh, no. What a dumb mistake! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

look at your conditions
you check if `num` is greater than 0 or `num` is less than 8.

10 is indeed greater than 0.

You need a `and` condition.

Answer (score 1):

In your condition, you say that if num is greater than 0 **or** less than 8 then return the value associated with the key num, but your greatest key is 8.
In the case of **or**, **only one** of the condition (greater than 0/less than 8) needs to be true, if you want it so that the if block only executes when **both** conditions are true, you can use **and** instead.
However, there's another way of doing what you want without using if conditions: by using `dict.get(key)` which will return the value of the key if it exists and None if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

'or' = execute if one of the statements is true
'and' = execute if all of the statements are true

As you used 'or' keyword' in your code, it will execute if num is greater than 0 or num is less than 8.
10 is less than 8; it meets one of your condition and continues to execute.
When it reaches 'day[num]', as there is no '10' key in your dictionary, it raises an error.

```
def return_day(num):
     days = {1:"Sunday", 2:"Monday", 3:"Tuesday", 4:"Wednesday", 5:"Thursday", 
6:"Friday", 7:"Saturday"}
    if (num > 0 or num < 8):  <----use 'and' instead of 'or'
        return days[num]
    return "None"
print(return_day(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

The "`or`" statement requires minimum one condition to be true to be equaled to true. A number is always higher than 0 or lower than 8.

What you need is the "`and`" statement, both of the condiitons need to be true for a valid date.

Correct code:

```
def return_day(num):
    days = {1:"Sunday", 2:"Monday", 3:"Tuesday", 4:"Wednesday", 5:"Thursday", 6:"Friday", 7:"Saturday"}
    if (num > 0 and num < 8):  # use the and keyword here
        return days[num]
    return "None"
    print(return_day(10))
```